# Is there a Pythonic way to create a list of cloned items?

Tags: python, list, instance, clone, construction

Consider the following code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None

some_list = [SomeClass()] * 5
```

The problem with this code is that all 5 items of `some_list` refer to the same instance of `SomeClass`. If I do `some_list[0].foo = 7`, then I get `some_list[1].foo` equal to `7`, etc.

So how to instantiate `N` different `SomeClass` instances in a list?

Comment: Your title reads as the opposite of what you want

Comment: @roganjosh, is it better now?

Comment: You're trying to create a list of class instances. "Cloned" implies, at least to me, references to the same object in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: use list comprehension

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None

some_list = [SomeClass() for _ in range(5)]
```